# Weird shadows when adding normal map

Tags: normal-map, shadows

can someone explain to me how i got these weird shadows and how to get rid of them? 
[image]

And another problem, when I use a normal map in the princepled shader it's not working and affecting the color, why is that? 
[image]

Thanks!

i already tried to recalculate the normals it didnt change anything

Comment: Also there may be duplicate and overlapping geometry

Comment: recalculating the normals is not fixing it, i found out its only when i add the normal map

Comment: Are there any objects at the same place overlapping with the shown one? (e.g. like duplicate of it) Did you check what's rendered with either Rendered shading mode or when rendering with F12? How does your normal map look like? How was it generated, baking from highpoly to lowpoly or baking data from image source? Provide more info about the project please. You can also share file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (make sure to pack textures if they are free of course, they are important here)